# Правильная структура в Mysql для meta_title meta_description meta_keywords

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Есть проект, в котором есть товары, статьи, и разные другие страницы, у которых есть meta_title meta_description meta_keywords.
На данный момент эти данные хранятся в табицах с контентом каждой из сущностей. Ну т.е. у таблицы products есть таблица product_content, у которой хранится все вышеперечисленное и свойственные ему данные. Такая же история и с, например статьями, категориями статей, категориями товаров, и т.д. Это вот сильно смущает. На данный момент склоняюсь к хранению вот этих общих полей в отдельной  таблице, условно, meta_content, и полиморфно связывать уже с любыми сущностями, там где это нужно.
Решение, в целом, мне нравится, но вот возникает вопрос в том, как это будет влиять на производительность в целом? Хорошая ли это практика, стоит ли так делать? В общем прошу совета.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё зависит от конкретного случая. Обычно в отдельные таблицы принято выносить данные только если в этом есть необходимость.

Например в opencart основная таблица содержит id товара и ряд свойств (вроде SKU, model, quanity) а в отдельной таблице лежат описание и мета данные. Но сделано это не просто так, а для мультиязычности. В разных таблицах под разные языки складываются данные о названии, описании и дальше выводятся в зависимости от выбранного в данный момент языка.

Обычно стараются сложить все необходимые для наиболее посещаемой страницы данные в одно место. Один большой запрос SELECT как правило обрабатывается быстрее, чем куча маленьких (даже если содержит JOIN) т.к. при каждом новом SELECT требуется время для передачи запроса и получение ответа + время работы сервера.

Всевозможные JOIN (для получения данных из других таблиц в рамках одного запроса) тоже слегка замедляет работу. А ещё очень сильно усложняет разработку, если у вас десяток JOIN, то разобраться в том что запрос берет и откуда - уже подвиг. (привет Битриксу).

Если же у вас очень много столбцов в той таблице где лежат мета данные, то оптимизацией будет не перенос их в отдельную таблицу, а изменение кода запроса с `SELECT * FROM` на `SELECT только нужные значения для данной страницы FROM`.

Вопрос производительности - он больше про грамотность написания запросов. То, как разложены данные на это влияет косвенно и определяется скорее функционалом ресурса/CMS/фреймворка.

Конкретно по Lavarel не могу дать совет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 
В целом в проекте есть требования к гибкости. Т.е. изначально закладываю возможность расшириться на мультиязычность и т.д. Что касается вот этих мета всех, то решил таки отдельной таблицей. Т.к. вот случай, когда поставили задачу, сделать шаблонизатор вот этих параметров. Будет сервис, который будет ходить по параметрам этих самых товаров, статей, и согласно шаблону формировать уже мета-тайтлы и т.д. Поскольку есть требование к гибкости, то и решение с одной таблицей - лучшее, потому как не придется писать дополнительных обработчиков в случае новых сущностей с шаблонами.